How to insert a page number in a specific location in a Footer in a Word Document
I have a macro that, when ran, will batch update the footer in a range of spec documents using a userform. When the user runs the macro, it first prompts to open a range of documents, then a userform appears. The userform has three input boxes where the user inputs information. The information in these forms is then put into the footer of all documents.  The footer contains information like store number, city, state, the section number, and date (corresponding to the input boxes in the userform). For this macro, the footer needs to be formatted as follows:
First Line centered - (Section number - Page number)
Line 2 empty
Third line left - (Store Number City, Date)
Third Line center - (Addendum or left blank)
Third line right - (document date)
Most of the documents have a naming scheme of ##### - ####.docx where the first 5 digits are the Section Number. So the Section number is found by taking the document name and subtracting the last 13 characters (not sure if this is the best way of doing this, I just need the first 5 digits for the section number).
The footers all come out formatted correctly, however what I am having trouble is getting the page number to show up on that first line after Section number - . Is there a way to get the page number to be placed here?
Here is the code that I currently have for Module 1:
Public varCityState       'make avail for the userform
Public varStoreNumber
Public varDate

Sub openAllfilesInALocation()
Dim doc
Dim i As Integer

Dim docToOpen As FileDialog
Set docToOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    docToOpen.Show

FooterForm.Show


For i = 1 To docToOpen.SelectedItems.Count
'Open each document
Set doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=docToOpen.SelectedItems(i))



With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)

    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = Left(ActiveDocument.Name, Len(ActiveDocument.Name) - 13) & "-" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & varCityState & vbTab & varStoreNumber & vbTab & varDate


End With

doc.Save
doc.Close

Next i

End Sub

Here is the code from the userform (FooterForm)
Else
varDate = CDate(varDate)
VBA.Unload FooterForm
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Assign the active document to the doc variable
Set doc = ActiveDocument

'Check if the document has a footer
If doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "This document does not have a footer.", vbExclamation
    Unload Me
    Exit Sub
End If

'Set the range to the footer of the first section
Set rng = doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

'Insert values aligned accordingly
rng.Text = StoreCityStateTextBox.Text & vbTab & AddorBlankTextBox.Text & vbTab & DateTextBox.Text
rng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
rng.Paragraphs(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
rng.Paragraphs(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight

'Unload the UserForm
Unload Me


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub



You need to use the Fields collection to insert a page number field at the correct position in the footer text.
The code should be as follows:
Sub openAllfilesInALocation()
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim varCityState As String
    Dim varStoreNumber As String
    Dim varDate As String
    Dim varSectionNumber As String

    Dim docToOpen As FileDialog
    Set docToOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    docToOpen.Show

    FooterForm.Show
    varCityState = InputBox("City")
    varStoreNumber = InputBox("Store Number")
    varDate = InputBox("Document Date")
    varSectionNumber = InputBox("Section Number")

    For i = 1 To docToOpen.SelectedItems.Count
        ' Open each document
        Set doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=docToOpen.SelectedItems(i))

        With doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
            ' Clear existing footer content
            .Text = ""

            ' First Line centered - (Section number - Page number)
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            .InsertAfter Text:=varSectionNumber & " - "
            .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            .Fields.Add Range:=doc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range, Type:=wdFieldPage
            .InsertParagraphAfter

            ' Move to the second line
            .InsertAfter vbNewLine

            ' Second Line left - (Store Number City, Date)
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
            .InsertAfter Text:=varStoreNumber & " " & varCityState & ", " & varDate

            ' Second Line center - (Addendum or left blank)
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            .InsertAfter vbTab & "Addendum" ' Change "Addendum" to "" if you want it blank

            ' Second Line right - (document date)
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
            .InsertAfter vbTab & varDate
        End With

        doc.Save
        doc.Close
    Next i
End Sub



Thank you.
However, I forgot to mention that the Section number of each document is pulled from the document name minus some characters - this is the "Len(ActiveDocument.Name) - 13)" comes from.
Also, all of the variables in my code under "FooterForm.Show" are commented out. The "Footer.Form" is actually a user form that contains the variables of Citystate, store number, and date. The addendum part we can leave out for now as its optional.
Anyway, when I use your code, all that appears is data entered from the userform on line 2 (left, center, and right) but there is nothing on line 2

I have updated my question with more information. Apologies that I didn't include this before.
